# Celery multi doesn't start workers

Tags: celery

I'm trying to start multiple workers on my server with command from celery docs `celery multi start Leslie -E`.
But it only shows:

```
celery multi v3.1.17 (Cipater)
> Starting nodes...
    > Leslie@test: OK
```

and exits.

And there are no workers in output of `ps aux | grep celery`.
Also I tried to start it on local machine and it works fine, I see 5 workers as expected.

So, what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had unsatisfactory results with the `celery multi` command. I think that  [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) works a lot better. You can find an example supervisord config file [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/extra/supervisord/celeryd.conf)

Comment: I need to start multiple workers. Supervisor allows to run only one.

Comment: not so. we run multiple workers with supervisor no problem. you can define multiple service stanzas in the config file - just copy the `[celery]` section and duplicate, rename it to e.g. `[celery-2]` and update the worker arguments as necessary.

Comment: not me)
thank you
I've added another service, It works :)

However it is still wondering why `multi` doesn't work.

Comment: yeah... I struggled with `multi` for a while - never could get it to work - just gave up in the end.